# appending values to textbox using for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add values to a textbox when looping through an array when checking checkboxes but as it is at the moment getting undefined.

Advice perhaps as to why the values are 'undefined'

```
    var txtBoxValues = [];
    $(document).on("click", "input[name=chkRelatedTopics]", function () {

    var nameAdminUser = $(this).val();
    var txtBox = document.getElementById("txtTraningTopics");
    txtBox.value = '';

    txtBoxValues.push(nameAdminUser);

    for (var i in txtBoxValues) {

        var str = txtBoxValues[i].value;
        txtBox.value += str + '; ';

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know how to use firebug or Chrome console? printing the value of txtBoxValues[i] would be enough to spot the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nameAdminUser` is already a string, so don't take `.value` from it.

You could replace

```
 var str = txtBoxValues[i].value;
```

with

```
 var str = txtBoxValues[i];
```

But instead of using this loop, and assuming you don't want, as I suppose, the last ";", you could also do

```
txtBox.value = txtBoxValues.join(';');
```

Answer (score 1):

`nameAdminUser` seems to be a String and in your for loop you expect an object. What if you simply do:

```
for (var i in txtBoxValues) {
    var str = txtBoxValues[i];
    txtBox.value += str + '; ';
}
```